# skill is not working to kill a session in Redhat 7 box

Tags: rhel, process, ksh, kill, hang

I had Redhat Linux 6.x which was recently upgraded to the Redhat 7 box.
Previously I used to use the below command to kill the linux sessions.
But now I am getting the the below error if I try to kill multiple sessions.

```
$ skill -kill pts/1 pts/0  pts/3
Memory fault
```

As per man pages I also tried but that also did not work.

```
skill -KILL -t /dev/pts/*
        Kill users on PTY devices.
```

I need to kill sessions in Redhat 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible answer if users are connected through ssh:

```
pkill -f <myusername>@pts/1
```

For other cases :

```
who -u
```

end then kill pid(s), or for example to kill all user sessions except root's one:

```
$ who -u | awk '!/^root /{print $6}' |xargs sudo kill
```

Comment: Thanks @tonioc for pkill suggestion. I liked it. Plus 1. I will wait till tomorrow to see if someone can advise why skill is not working. If not I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Noting that [skill](https://linux.die.net/man/1/skill)'s man page says:

> These tools are probably obsolete and unportable. The command syntax is poorly defined. Consider using the killall, pkill, and pgrep commands instead

I believe the syntax you're looking for is:

```
skill -t pts/0 -t pts/1 -t pts/3
```

... as it appears that the `expression` syntax requires one tty per `-t` flag.

As to why skill is not actually killing the processes, my suspicion is that the format of /proc/PID/stat changed since skill was compiled, causing it to skip past the process in the [check_proc function](https://github.com/mmalecki/procps/blob/master/skill.c#L119) (in an arbitrary github copy of skill.c I found). It appears to parse /proc/PID/stat manually, and never sends a kill signal to the process(es):

```
open("/proc/21102/stat", O_RDONLY)      = 4
read(4, "21102 (bash) S 21101 21102 21102"..., 128) = 128
```

...

```
open("/proc/22839/stat", O_RDONLY)      = 4
read(4, "22839 (view) S 21102 22839 21102"..., 128) = 128
```

When I compile a fresh copy of skill, it functions as intended:

```
open("/proc/22926/stat", O_RDONLY)      = 4
read(4, "22926 (bash) S 22925 22926 22926"..., 128) = 128
readlink("/proc/22926/tty", 0x7f3e47e073e0, 127) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
readlink("/proc/22926/fd/2", "/dev/pts/2", 127) = 10
kill(22926, SIGKILL)                    = 0
```

---

I would follow the suggestion of the manpage and [tonioc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425668/117549) and switch to `pkill`; for example, to kill processes on pts/1 and/or pts/2:

```
pkill -HUP -t pts/1,pts/2
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff Schaller for detailed explanation. Upvoted and Yes I will use pkill.